# Java time off by 1 hour when run on Ubuntu vs Windows

Tags: java, windows, spring-boot, ubuntu, time

I have a microservice written in Java + using Spring Boot. I developed it on Windows 10 using Java version 1.8.0_221. Now I want to run this on Ubuntu 18.04. On Ubuntu machine I have OpenJDK 1.8.0_40-b25.

When I run this on Windows machine the time displayed on console messages(I print them using log4j2) and time of stuff I save on database(using @CreatedDate and @Temopral(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) annotation on a Date field) is correct and my ZoneId.systemDefault is Europe/Istanbul.

It is also Europe/Istanbul on my Ubuntu machine.

However when I run this on Ubuntu machine the time is 1 hour behind the system time I get by typing "date" on terminal. All the times on logs I print to console and my database insertions are off by one hour.

I have searched other similar questions but they all focused on timezones, I don't think in any part of the program I am modifying the timezone. Also my Ubuntu time being correct makes me thing I need to change something with JVM maybe?

Comment: are the shown system times of windows and ubuntu equal?

Comment: Yes, didn't check second-by-second but they are equal to the minutes.

Comment: Unsure: Turkey had changed its DST settings in 2019, of which your Ubuntu 18.04 might not be aware of. I have no experience with Turkish time or java updates of locale specific data, but that would be one very prosaic explanation. Check the UTC times.

Comment: Yes Turkey did stop doing daylight savings but my ubuntu time is correct. I tought java would simply pull operating system's time.

Comment: Looks like DST issue, check this : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/troubleshoot/time-zone-settings-jre.htm#JSTGD366

Comment: Java has its own timezone database.

Comment: @Thilo True. Does that fact explain anything here?

Comment: Are those annotations coming from Spring Data rather than Spring Boot? If so, you should edit your tags and text to tell the whole story.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to update the timezone database following the answer to this question [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29101788/how-do-i-update-the-timezone-information-for-the-openjdk) but could not get it to work. So I decided to remove OpenJDK and install Oracle JDK 8 instead and it works fine now.

Comment: Are you aware that you have to pay a yearly license fee for using OracleJDK?

Comment: Didn't know that! I guess I will try to get OpenJDK to work then.