# DateTimeParseException could not be parsed at index 20

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, datetimeparseexception

Why this code worked fine in intellij but throw an exception when running in Android studio?

```
fun main() {
    val date = "Wed Mar 31 17:27:07 ICT 2021"
    println(date.toEpochSecond())
}

fun String.toEpochSecond(): Long {
    val dbResponsePattern = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"
    val dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dbResponsePattern)
    return ZonedDateTime.parse(this, dateTimeFormatter).toInstant().epochSecond
}
```

also this one

```
fun main() {
    val date = "Wed Mar 31 17:27:07 ICT 2021"
    println(date.toEpochSecond())
}

fun String.toEpochSecond(): Long {
    val dbResponsePattern = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"
    val dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dbResponsePattern)
    return Date.from(
            LocalDateTime.parse(this, dateTimeFormatter)
                    .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                    .toInstant()
    ).toInstant().epochSecond
}
```

When the exception occurs the text was exact same text i used here.

Exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.wo1f.the_earth, PID: 16409
    java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Wed Mar 31 17:27:07 ICT 2021' could not be parsed at index 20
        at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
        at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
        at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:486)
        at com.wo1f.base_android.DateMapperKt.toEpochSecond(DateMapper.kt:17)
        at com.wo1f.domain.usecases.SyncProfile.syncPost(SyncProfile.kt:46)
        at com.wo1f.domain.usecases.SyncProfile.access$syncPost(SyncProfile.kt:15)
        at com.wo1f.domain.usecases.SyncProfile$invoke$2$1$invokeSuspend$$inlined$collect$1.emit(Collect.kt:144)
        at com.wo1f.domain.usecases.SyncProfile$invoke$2$1$invokeSuspend$$inlined$collect$1$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:15)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Smells like the name `ICT` might not be defined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java DateTimeFormatterBuilder fails on testtime \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526234/java-datetimeformatterbuilder-fails-on-testtime)

Comment: Thanks. The `index 20` mentioned in the exception message confirms what has been said about `ICT` (possibly meant to mean Indochina Time?)  is not recognized.

Comment: @OleV.V. there was a problem with java date time and android Api i need to add additional dependencies and `compileOptions` to use it

Comment: @OleV.V. i hate this date format i got this date from mongodb response idk why u might know the original mongodb date is ISO8601 UTC

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused if you are using different version of Timezone database. By default java gets Timezone information from [IANA Timezone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), which comes with java installation. this database is subject to change and two different JRE's might be using two different versions of this database. you can verify the database version in use as

```
java -jar tzupdater.jar -V
```

It seems the JRE being used by intellij is using outdated IANA Timezone database, which included ICT zone, this must be a version earlier then 2017, as ICT and other invented timezones were removed in [2017 release](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2017-February/000045.html)

> **Changes to past and future time zone abbreviations**
>
> Switch to numeric time zone abbreviations for South America, as
> part of the ongoing project of removing invented abbreviations.
> This avoids the need to invent an abbreviation for the new Chilean
> new zone.  Similarly, switch from invented to numeric time zone
> abbreviations for Afghanistan, American Samoa, the Azores,
> Bangladesh, Bhutan, the British Indian Ocean Territory, Brunei,
> Cape Verde, Chatham Is, Christmas I, Cocos (Keeling) Is, Cook Is,
> Dubai, East Timor, Eucla, Fiji, French Polynesia, Greenland,
> **Indochina**

To get the currently available zoneIds, you can enquire the jvm as

```
java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()
// or
ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()
```

Comment: Invalid test. A time zone with ID, say, Asia/Bangkok, could be formatted into `ICT` when the formatter contains `z` for short time zone name. And parsed back from such a string. Not that it’s recommended. It isn’t.

Comment: @mightyWOZ i can't run that. `Error: Unable to access jarfile tzupdater.jar
`

Comment: @jorieitomuke You must obtain an implementation of `tzupdater`. [Oracle provides one](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/tzupdater-readme.html). But read the license terms first. And I don't know if that works for non-Oracle-branded binary installations of JDK or not. Another idea: You may be able to manually replace the [`tzdata`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) file yourself within your existing JDK installation. See [*How do I update the timezone information for the OpenJDK?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29101788/642706).

Comment: @Basil Bourque That seems complicated to me. I've already moved this code to my server. Thanks for helping!